# Name in swap slot show the same name for stage and production in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have production deployment scheduled for this weekend and when we were checking the swap slot feature in web apps it had a new UI, now it shows few characters of the slot name which has the format of production slot name/stage slot name.

This naming convention is not set by me. While creating slot(a long time ago) the azure automatically took it as "production slot name/stage slot", but my input was stage slot name only.

I have multiple stage slots. Now i am not sure which slots are the one I need to swap. Can Azure team look into this or give a workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The naming convention of slots added to the webapp is like Name_of_the_webapp(Name_of_the_slot). Example - If the name of webapp is WEBAPP and name of the slot is STAGING (Entered while adding the slot to webapp), then the name of the Staging slot will be like WEBAPP(STAGING).

Since the name of your production slot is a bit long, the entire name of the other slots with the brackets () is not being visible to you. I was able to reproduce the same issue on my subscription as well. We are not able to see the complete name of the slots by even hovering over the options listed.

This might need a UI fix on the portal. Will update you back on this thread.

Comment: This is a known issue, we will fix it soon. thanks for reporting it!